# Probability law (Multiplication Law)

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

10 marbles are in an urn, 4 are Red and 6 are Black.
For randomly selecting three marbles without replacement, what is the probability all three are black?

Let's say A is an event where 1st one is black, B is an event 2nd one is black, C is an event 3rd one is black.

This is what I tried:
I understand how to solve this using the counting method, but I don't understand the step that I marked with the question mark in the picture. Can someone help me understand how we use multiplication rule when we have more than 2 events?
[image]

Comment: So we know that $P(B \cap C) = P(B) P(C | B)$. However, in the picture, we have already conditioned on $A$. So the $P(B)$ is now $P(B|A)$ and $P(C|B)$ is $P(C|A\cap B)$

Answer (score 1):

In order to understand the validity of the 2nd approach, you have to learn about [Bayes Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes%27_theorem) which states that

given two events $R$ and $S$, with $p(RS)$ representing the probability of both events occurring, you have that

$p(S)p(R|S) = p(RS).$

Therefore, $p(A)p(B|A) = p(AB).$

Further, $p(AB)p(C|AB) = p(ABC).$